# Creating MXML components via an ActionScript loop in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, foreach, flash-builder, mxml

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 to create an app for a uni project. I have a custom Spark component, and I need to dynamically create a number of instances of that component at runtime depending on the number of XML elements returned via a PHP script.

That might be a bit confusing, so let me write the steps:
1) The application sends an HTTPService request to a PHP script hosted on the server.
2) The PHP accesses the SQL database and returns a series of XML data.
3) The ActionScript dynamically creates X instances of my custom Flex component, where X is the number of data in the XML.

Here's the code I've got so far (untidy because I'm trying to make it work):

ActionScript:

```
        [Bindable]
        public var holderArray:Array = new Array(100);

        public function createMenu(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var count:int = 0;
            var curMenuItem:menuItemContainer = new menuItemContainer();
            while (count < loadedMenu.length){
                curMenuItem.itemName = loadedMenu.getItemAt(count).name;
                curMenuItem.itemDesc = loadedMenu.getItemAt(count).description;
                curMenuItem.itemPrice = numForm.format(loadedMenu.getItemAt(count).price);                  
                curMenuItem.imageFile = loadedMenu.getItemAt(count).url;
                //curMenuItem.y = count * 120
                //menuItemGroup.addElement(curMenuItem);
                holderArray[count] = curMenuItem;
                count ++;
            }
            //testString = holderArray[1].itemName;
            var count2:int = 0;
            for each (var menuItem:menuItemContainer in holderArray){
                menuItem.name = "menuItem" + count2;
                menuItem.id = "menuItem" + count2;
                //testString += menuItem.name;
                menuItemGroup.addElement(menuItem);
                count2++;
            }
        }
```

MXML:

```
<s:VGroup id="menuItemGroup" x="40" y="150">
</s:VGroup>
```

What seems to be happening with that code is that each of my three XML data that get returned are being used in instances of menuItemContainer, but when each one is added to menuItemGroup, it's overwriting the one that's already there. I'm not sure if the item is actually getting overwritten, or if the new item is just sitting atop the earlier ones, but if the latter is true I can't find a way to arrange the components. I've tried setting menuItem.y in the loop (as a function of count2), but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions/answers.
Benjamin.

Comment: Looks like someone already gave you the correct answer. My only other comment, is that you may consider displaying your items in a list w/ an itemRenderer and an XMLListCollection instead of manually creating children and placing them inside a Group.

Comment: I have to back @www.Flextras.com on this one: you should use a List or a DataGroup (or a Repeater in Flex 3) in this kind of situation. Much easier.

Comment: I'm still learning a lot of Flex stuff. I've only been using it for a few months. There seems to be a lot of different ways to achieve anything (as with most programming). If I use an XMLListCollection, how would I display that in the app? I tried using a DataGroup but I didn't get far.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line

```
var curMenuItem:menuItemContainer = new menuItemContainer();
```

inside your while loop. With your code as it is you are only creating one instance of `menuItemContainer` then continually changing the properties of that one `menuItemContainer` in your while loop. Instead you need to create a new, different instance of `menuItemContainer` with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yep, that's done it, thank you. I thought that adding them to the VGroup in each iteration would display an instance of the object with its current data, but it seems I was wrong.

Thanks again!
B.